# How to check if occurrences of identical consecutive numbers is below a threshold in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, list

I need to check if the occurrences of identical consecutive numbers is below a certain threshold, e.g. maximal two same consecutive numbers.

```
pd.Series(data=[-1, -1, 2, -2, 2, -2, 1, 1])  # True
pd.Series(data=[-1, -1, -1, 2, 2, -2, 1, 1])  # False
```

Further checks:
Only the numbers `+1` and `-1` are allowed to occur as consecutive numbers with a maximum of two occurrences.

```
pd.Series(data=[-1, 1, -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1])  # True
pd.Series(data=[1, 1, -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1])  # True
pd.Series(data=[-1, -1, 2, 2, -2, 1, 1, -2])  # False
pd.Series(data=[-1, 1, -2, -2, 1, -1, 2, -2]) # False
```

Comment: I would expect all outputs in the second part to be True, there is never more than two successive 1/-1

Comment: That's true, however, there must not be any consecutive +2 or -2.

Comment: Then sorry but you should make the question more explicit. Do you mean that you can have 2 consecutive 1 but only 1 "consecutive" 2?

Comment: I updated answer with a generic approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `shift` method along with Boolean indexing to achieve this. The idea is to compare each element with the previous one, and if they are equal and not equal to +1 or -1, return False.

Here's an example implementation:

```
def check_consecutive(series):
    consecutive = (series == series.shift()).values
    allowed = ((series == 1) | (series == -1)).values
    return (consecutive & ~allowed).sum() <= 2

print(check_consecutive(pd.Series(data=[-1, -1, 2, -2, 2, -2, 1, 1]))) # True
print(check_consecutive(pd.Series(data=[-1, -1, -1, 2, 2, -2, 1, 1]))) # False
print(check_consecutive(pd.Series(data=[-1, 1, -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1]))) # True
print(check_consecutive(pd.Series(data=[1, 1, -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1]))) # True
print(check_consecutive(pd.Series(data=[-1, -1, 2, 2, -2, 1, 1, -2]))) # False
print(check_consecutive(pd.Series(data=[-1, 1, -2, -2, 1, -1, 2, -2]))) # False
```